# How can I filter exported tickets from database using Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am working on a Django based web project where we handle tickets based requests. I am working on an implementation where I need to export all closed tickets everyday.

My ticket table database looks like,

```
-------------------------------------------------
| ID | ticket_number | ticket_data |  is_closed |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1 |    123123     | data 1      |      1     |
-------------------------------------------------
|  2 |    123124     | data 2      |      1     |
-------------------------------------------------
|  3 |    123125     | data 3      |      1     |
-------------------------------------------------
|  4 |    123126     | data 4      |      1     |
-------------------------------------------------
```

And my ticket_exported table in database is similar to

```
----------------------------------
| ID | ticket_id | ticket_number |
----------------------------------
| 10 |     1     |     123123    |
----------------------------------
| 11 |     2     |     123124    |
----------------------------------
```

so my question is that when I process of exporting tickets, is there any way where I can make a single query to  get list of all tickets which are closed but `ticket_id` and `ticket_number` is not in `ticket_exported` table? So when I run functions it should get tickets with `ticket_id` '3' and '4' because they are not exported in `ticket_export` database.

I don't want to go through all possible tickets and check one by one if their id exists in exported tickets table if I can just do it in one query whether it is raw SQL query or Django's queries.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Not sure what the use case is here or if there are additional columns, but wouldn't it be simpler to have a 'is_exported' field like the 'is_closed' one?

Comment: @JensAstrup it can be, I think that is one of simplest idea. Thanks!!!

Comment: @JensAstrup post your answer, I will accept it so you can get points.

Comment: Aren't you using the ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment- you could probably save yourself a bunch of trouble and just add another BooleanField for `'is_exported'` instead of having a separate model assuming there aren't fields specific to TicketExported.

@doniyor's answer gets you the queryset you're looking for though. In response to your raw SQL statement question: you want: `unexported_tickets.query`.

Answer (score 2):

you can do without `is_exported` field:

```
exported_tickets = TicketsExported.objects.all()
unexported_tickets = Tickets.object.exclude(id__in=[et.id for et in exported_tickets])
```

but `is_exported` field can be useful somewhere else